# Angular testing mocking store.pipe in component

Tags: unit-testing

I have a container which host different component.  The angular service call the restAPI and update the store with data. Now the component fetch data from store something like below on nginit() below getEmloyeeState is selector which gets data from store.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.store.pipe(select(getEmployeeState)).subscribe(emp => {
      this.employee = emp;
    });
  }
```

To test the component I am trying to mock store.pipe like below.

```
beforeEach(() => {
mockStore = jasmine.createSpyObj('store', ['pipe']);

 it('When ngOnInit called, it should initlize emp object',
            () => {
              mockStore.pipe.and.callFake(() => {
                return {
                  subscribe: (callback) => {
                    callback({
                      empObj: empObj
                    })
                  }
                }
              });
              empComponent.ngOnInit();
              expect(empComponent.employee.empId).toEqual('EMP1000');
            });
        });
```

looks like mocking store.pipe pass through but in ngOnInit the employee object is not getting initialize as it return **Expected undefined to equal EMP1000**
any suggestion/help  would be appreciated.